# how to open a java vpn within parallels (8, with "coherence") under a mac

Tags: remote-desktop, vpn, java, parallels

I use Parallels 8 with Windows XP 64-bit, and during the installation I opted for the option to have mac-like windows for applications (is this "Coherence"?).

However, now I am confused how to do the following: log in to a site in explorer and let it open a Java VPN channel, which then would allow a Remote Desktop Connection client to connect to the remote site via this tunnel. I can fire up IE, but how would the RDC  know about the tunnel?

Or would my whole mac's traffic routed through the VPN now?

If I should go back to non-mac-like interface, how can I do that without reinstalling?

Comment: Currently, the Java pop-up windows opens, but the VPN connection is not established. So the problem is not the channel is open but it is browser-only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn off coherence, open Parallels, go to Preferences, then you will see the coherence/window options. You can turn on regular Windows (or Ubuntu, etc) interface there.

Thinking it over, I can't see how a VPN running as an applet in the browser can do anything more than tunnel for itself. Your best bet would be to install a VPN or use OS X's built in VPN instead.

Comment: Thanks! The VPN still does not build up. As it is only supposed to work in IE, I don't have much room to experiment whether my browser is somehow "broken" (old, locked down etc.) or 64-bit WinXP breaks the website's code or only Parallels simply does not allow such VPN opened up within the VM by a browser. Any thoughts on these possibilities?